# jquery is not working in aspx page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I want to call one jquery function in an input button click event in aspx page.

here is the code,

```
<input type="button" id="filter" name="filter" value="Filter" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#filter").click(function () {
            alert('clicked!');
        });
    });
</script>
```

this code is working in other page like html. but it is not working in aspx page.

I dont know that why this code is not working in aspx page

Thanks.

Comment: Can you check for conflicts, also try with $.noConflict() or jQuery.noConflict() , also check if there is only single jQuery file included.

Comment: did you have any error in  browser console ?

Comment: Try `$("#<%= filter.ClientID %>").click(function () {`

Comment: Yes @JYoThI. It is showing "ReferenceError: $ is not defined" of message

Comment: you need to include the jquery   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: check my below answer @s.k.Soni

Comment: @JYoThI, I have include that link which you have given me but then also the same issues is coming.

Comment: Strange , i tried it in my mvc view and its working fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your comment `It is showing "ReferenceError: $ is not defined" of message`  you need to include the jquery library in your aspx page .

```js
    $(function () {
        $("#filter").click(function () {
            alert('clicked!');
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" id="filter" name="filter" value="Filter" />
```

Comment: yah got it. Thank you. :)

Comment: glad to help you @s.k.Soni

Answer (score -3):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $("#filter").click(function () {
        alert('clicked!');
       return false;
    });
});
```